# Implementation of Queues in Linked Lists

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I am given these structure declarations in order to implement a queue collection that uses a circular linked list.

```
typedef struct intnode {
    int value;
    struct intnode *next;
} intnode_t;

typedef struct {
    intnode_t *rear;   // Points to the node at the tail of the 
                       // queue's linked list
    int size;          // The # of nodes in the queue's linked list
} intqueue_t;

intnode_t *intnode_construct(int value, intnode_t *next)
{
    intnode_t *p = malloc(sizeof(intnode_t));
    assert (p != NULL);
    p->value = value;
    p->next = next;
    return p;
}


/* Return a pointer to a new, empty queue.
 * Terminate (via assert) if memory for the queue cannot be allocated.
 */

intqueue_t *intqueue_construct(void)
{
    intqueue_t *queue = malloc(sizeof(intqueue_t));
    assert(queue != NULL);

    queue->rear = NULL;
    queue->size = 0;
    return queue;
}
```

I'm trying to create a function that will enqueue at a specified value (append it to the rear of the queue), and I need to consider the two cases in which the queue is empty and when the queue has one or more elements. This is the code I have so far:

```
void intqueue_enqueue(intqueue_t *queue, int value)
{

    intnode_t *p = intnode_construct(value, NULL);

    if(queue->rear->next == NULL) {
        //the queue is empty
        queue->rear->next =p;
    } else {
        //the queue is not empty
        queue->rear=p;
    }
    queue->rear=p;
    queue->size++;
}
```

This code gives me a runtime error so I'm not sure whats wrong. In the code, I'm assuming queue->rear->next is the front, however I think this is where the problem might be. All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How are you running the code? Where do you call intqueue_construct?

Comment: "I'm assuming `queue->rear->next` is the front"  is dubious. If `queue == NULL` or `queue->rear == NULL` the code breaks. Assume nothing.

Comment: Closely related to previous questions by the same OP: [How to implement a queue in a linked list in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614640/how-to-implement-a-queue-in-a-linked-list-in-c) and [How to call the front of the queue in a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614015/how-to-call-the-front-of-the-queue-in-a-linked-list)

Comment: Since intqueue_t only has a rear and size, I wasn't sure what to use when I call the front, since it is a circular queue and the next value after rear would go back to front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem occurs on this line:

```
if(queue->rear->next == NULL) {
```

The first time you call the function, queue->rear is NULL. Thus when you try to dereference it to get `queue->rear->next` you get the runtime error.

To fix this code, update `intqueue_enqueue` to just check if `queue->size==0`, and if so then you need to initialize it by setting `queue->rear=p` and `p->next=p`. Then update the `else` clause so that it inserts the element between the two existing elements. Hint: you'll need to store `queue->rear->next` in `p`.

### Edit

To address your comment, here's how to graphically think about a list with three elements:

```
<element1: next==element2> <element2: next==element3> <element3: next==element1>
```

And `queue->rear` points to `element3`. So, to insert a fourth element, you need to make it so that `queue->rear` points to `element4` and  `element4->rear` needs to point to `element1`. Remember that the location of `element` is stored in `rear->next`.

Comment: I was told that for this code, in a circular linked list, the tail node (the node at the rear of the queue) points to the head node (the node at the front of the queue). We don't need variable front.

Comment: Oh okay, that's somewhat unusual but I guess it's a good exercise. The first part of my answer still answers your question. I'll update the second half to reflect a circular linked list.

Comment: The code works for when the queue is empty when it is not empty, I get another runtime error.
 
  `queue->rear->next=p;
 }

    queue->rear=p;
    queue->size++;

 
    }`

Comment: You'll need to assign `p->next` to something, that's what I was alluding to in my hint. What do you think it should point to?

Comment: would `p->next = queue->rear`?

Comment: Nope, think about it graphically: let's say I have three elements and I am trying to insert a fourth. I'll update my answer since it is hard to write in comments.

Comment: Oh okay, so `p->next = queue->rear->next`